# Django: foreign key value in a list display admin

Tags: python, django, django-admin

I'm trying to display the foreign key 'company name' in the admin list view. However, the list view just shows (None) for the company. What I'm I doing wrong?

**admin.py**

```
class CampaignAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    #fields = ['name', 'Company_name', 'active', 'modified', 'created']
    list_display = ['name', 'related_company', 'active', 'modified', 'created']
    list_filter = ['active']
    search_fields = ['name']
    sortable_field_name = "name"
    autocomplete_lookup_fields = {
        'name': ['name'],
        }

    def related_company(self, obj):
        return '%s'%(obj.Company.name)
    related_company.short_description = 'Company'


admin.site.register(Campaign, CampaignAdmin)
```

**model.py**

```
class Company(models.Model):
    companyid = models.CharField(max_length=255, primary_key=True, db_column='companyID')
    name = models.CharField(max_length=105)
    logourl = models.CharField(max_length=255, db_column='logoURL')
    website = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True)
    active = HibernateBooleanField(default=False)
    created = models.DateTimeField()
    modified = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)

    class Meta:
        db_table = u'company'
        ordering = ['name']

    @staticmethod
    def autocomplete_search_fields():
        return ("id__iexact", "name__icontains",)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name


class Campaign(models.Model):
    campaignid = models.CharField(max_length=255, primary_key=True, db_column='campaignID')
    name = models.CharField(max_length=105)
    active = HibernateBooleanField(default=False)
    created = models.DateTimeField()
    modified = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)
    companyid = models.ForeignKey(Company, null=True, db_column='companyID', blank=True)

    class Meta:
        db_table = u'campaign'


    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name
```

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Your `Campaign` model has no `Company` attribute - the ForeignKey is the field `companyid`. You'd need to change your function to

```
def related_company(self, obj):
    return obj.companyid.name
related_company.short_description = 'Company'
```

And since the `__unicode__()` method of the company object returns the name anyway, you probably don't need the custom function anyway - I think you can put the foreign key field directly in the display list:

```
list_display = ['name', 'companyid', 'active', 'modified', 'created']
```

Comment: Also the string interpolation is pointless: should just be `return obj.companyid.name`.

Answer (score 0):

An additional feature to consider when you're linking to a ForeignKey object in this way is to set `related_company.allow_tags = True` on the function.

This will make it so you can return HTML and have it be rendered as a usable link in the listview.